# Is there any way to prevent the user from deleting the installed application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is there any way to prevent the user from deleting the installed application? I know the system application can not be deleted. But we can delete all the installed application. But is there any API to capture the application deletion.

Comment: What system is this? Mac OS X or iPhone?

Comment: It is iPhone or iPod Touch device.

Answer (score 4):

You certainly can't prevent *any* user from deleting your app.  To be honest I'm rather glad it's not possible! Imagine the rubbish you'd end up with stuck on your device..

However, if you have physical access to the device and want to prevent your kids from deleting apps, or (I guess) your employees in a business setting you can do the following:

- Go to Settings / General / Restrictions
- Ensure restrictions are set to ON.
- Provide a passcode
- Scroll down to 'Deleting Apps' and set it to 'OFF'

You can do the same for installing new apps here, and a bunch of other options.